# file_get_contents is picking up all code instead of just the text

Tags: php, file-get-contents

$text = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/name.php?name=Lary");

I want to use it to get only the text, not the html.

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Can I post again in 40 minutes, since you are here, could you answer my question?

Comment: And what *is* your question?  What specifically is the problem you're trying to solve?  Explain the details.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I haven't tested yet.

```
$html = file_get_contents("http://127.0.0.1/name.php?name=Lary");

$text = strip_tags($html);

echo ($text);
```

More info here: [strip_tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)